# Google Charts from sheets throwing - All series on a given axis must be of the same data type error when specific range is selected

Tags: charts, google-visualization

[Sheets and Range Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91gPV.jpg)

When I am trying to run below code with Sheets Range "A:B" it works and when selecting "E:F" it's throwing an Error. 
Please refer the the image for sample data and the spreadsheet is made accessible for checking the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Excel Pull Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> 
  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  // google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawSheetName);

   // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.


  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  //  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSheetName);

function drawSheetName() {
      var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A:B10');

      var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Di7YkPars5zJs512RhM1wLEhfxUQfavgs6Z2GCIppV4/edit#gid=0&headers=1&tq='+queryString);

      query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var data = response.getDataTable();
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, { height: 400 });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the url for the sheet,
change --> `edit#` -- to --> `gviz/tq?`

as in...

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Di7YkPars5zJs512RhM1wLEhfxUQfavgs6Z2GCIppV4/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq='+queryString);
```

this will let you select specific columns...

see following working snippet, which only selects column A...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['table']
}).then(drawSheetName);

function drawSheetName() {
  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A');

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Di7YkPars5zJs512RhM1wLEhfxUQfavgs6Z2GCIppV4/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq='+queryString);

  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, { height: 400 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

ALSO, you're using an old version of google charts.
`jsapi` should no longer be used, see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code),
this will only change the `load` statement.

from...

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawSheetName);
```

to...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSheetName);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and also about the updated library. For Table it's working absolutely fine, not for Charts. 

https://bharathvullanki.com/ - show step count data in Charts

Just to give a background: This is what I am trying to achieve on my word press site and it's showing correctly with the old code that I pasted, just that it's not picking up a specific range. I had to work around the creating a new sheet with Aggregate values of step count. I really appreciate if you can check if there is anything specific for Charts that I would need to work out.